# Using the results of geoprocess function in another geoprocess function

Tags: arcpy, python-3, value-list, results

I have a list to hold the iterated results of running `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer` and 'arcpy.CopyFeatures` geoprocesses.

```
selectList = []
fip = '13245'
for fc in featureclasses:
     select = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "temp_lyr","FIPS_CODE = '{}'".format(fip))
     arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/Sandbox/selects.gdb"
     selectFeatures = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(select, "select_{}".format(fip))
     selectList.append(selectFeatures)
```

When I `print(selectList)` it gives me a weird list of results:

```
[<Result'C:\\Workspace\\Sandbox\\MapChangeProject\\selects.gdb\\select_13245'>, <Result 'C:\\Workspace\\Sandbox\\MapChangeProject\\selects.gdb\\select_06037'>]
```

What I want to do is merge all of these results together into one feature like this:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(selectList, "merge")
```

What am I doing wrong here and how do I get my results into a format that will work for my merge?

Comment: you have a result object so try this,
result = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(select, "select_{}".format(fip))
selectFeatures = result.getOutput(0)

Comment: @klewis is on the right path but I would like to point out that for each iteration of fc your selected features will be overwritten as the value for fip doesn't change in the loop so what you'll end up with is just the last feature class len(featureclasses) times. Try changing the output of copy features to "in_memory\\select_{}".format(fc) then selectList.append( "in_memory\\select_{}".format(fc)) then perform a loop after the merge **for fc in selectList: del fc** to clean up... assuming you have plenty of memory otherwise ensure your env.overwriteOutput == True or the script will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arcpy geoprocessing tools return a [Result](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) object. Result objects cannot be used as inputs into other geoprocessing tools. You'll need the path to the tool output to populate your list.

```
selectList = []
fip = '13245'
for fc in featureclasses:
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "temp_lyr","FIPS_CODE = '{}'".format(fip))
     arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/Sandbox/selects.gdb"
     selectFeatures = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("temp_lyr", "select_{}".format(fip))
     selectList.append("select_{}".format(fip))
```